# Snapping lines to the same point when more than 2 lines are intersecting

Tags: qgis, line, snapping

In case vertices are close enough (i.e. 7m) I want to snap lines to a single point when there are more than two lines intersecting.
Is there an easy way of doing this for all the similar intersections in a large line data?

[image]

Comment: Is the orange line is a one line, or are there three orange lines?

Comment: Nice point to make the problem clearer, there are 3 lines